# Autosys monthly Job schedule

Tags: unix, autosys

I am trying to schedule a Job in Autosys and I would like this job to run once a month. Say, 5th day of every month. Could you please help how we can configure this in Autosys?

I did some research and came to know that we need to create a calendar in Autosys. Could someone please help how we can create and configure such a calendar in autosys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways to create a calendar with tools provided with Autosys. The commands to launch the tools are `autocal` (which is a graphical editor) and `autocal_asc` (which is a text-based editor). The executables are available in the Autosys root user directory (e.g. /etc/autosys). I would recommend using the graphical interface, since it gives some options which will make it easier on you.

Once the utility is running, you should be able to create a new calendar (File > New). Give it a name (e.g. 5thOfTheMonth), and choose Edit > Apply Rule. Here you can configure the day(s) of the month you wish to run the job on, and many other options.

Once the calendar is created and saved, you can tie a job to it using the `run_calendar` JIL command (`run_calendar: 5thOfTheMonth`) or specifying the calendar in the Job Definition > Date/Time Options graphical interface.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I checked out the calendar option - however, I need to add an entry in the calendar for every month. For example, I need to add the dates Oct 5 2011, Nov 5 2011, Dec 5 2011, Jan 5 2012 and so on... Is there a generic way of specifying the dates since I want the job to run on the 5th of every month indefinitely.

Comment: You should be able to use the calendar rule editor to set this up easily. In `autocal`, go to Edit > Apply Rule, under `Date Selection Rule` > `Occurrences` you should be able to choose First, Second, etc or enter your own (in your case, 5th). For the indefinite part, you can specify a date range of today until 12/31/9999 in the same screen.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I could not get "autocal" (GUI) running since I'm working on a remote machine. Hence I could only use "autocal_asc"(text based calendar). Is there way to specify rules through the text based editor?

Answer (score 1):

```
make an extended calendar, like this-

5th_day_every_month
-------------------
Enter Name: 5th_day_evry_mnth  
Enter Workdays [XXXXX..]:  
Enter Non-workday Actions [' ',O,N,W,P]:  
Enter Holiday Actions [' ',O,S,N,W,P]:  
Enter Holiday Calendar [none]:  
Enter Cycle Name [none]:  
Enter Date Adjustment [0]:  
Enter Date Conditions [DAILY]: MNTHD#5
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have an Autosys web portal that allows you to import a calendar from a file, you can define an extended calendar inside a file. For the condition attribute of the extended calendar, you can specify a day of the month with `MNTHD#nn`, where `nn` is the `nn`th day of the month.

The extended calendar can be defined like

```
extended_calendar: fifth_of_month
condition: MNTHD#5
```

and you can include the calendar as the `run_calendar` attribute of your job like

```
insert_job: job_name
run_calendar: fifth_of_month
```

Find more information [here](https://communities.ca.com/thread/241757515) on the different conditions for an extended calendar.